# Kubuntu flash fullscreen glitches

Tags: video, firefox, flash, kubuntu, fullscreen

machine: thinkpad edge14 kubuntu 11.04 x64 w/ firefox flash64 and java6

1. when launching fullscreen flash videos, the video will be placed on the background and the main window has to be minimized to view the video (this glitch can be replicated on windows7x64 as well so I'm assuming this is either flash or firefox problem)
2. related to problem #1; the first problem wouldn't be too much of a trouble if minimizing the window worked all the time; sometimes the flash video doesn't get redrawn into fullscreen; I click the fullscreen button, the video freezes but audio continues, minimize window and nothing happens, restore original window and the video continues in the embedded player; sometimes have to click the fullscreen quite a few times for it to actually be redrawn to fullscreen
3. related to problem #1; when minimizing the main window to view the fullscreen video in the background, the taskbar remains in view and doesn't get transposed by the video (problem for sites like megavideo where the video seekbar is at the bottom of the screen and cannot be accessed due to the protruding taskbar; temporary fix is to switch the taskbar visibility settings from "always visible" to "windows can cover")
4. and lastly, when launching a flash video to fullscreen the screen completely blackens (sometimes w/ audio and sometimes w/out) and the entire desktop environment is inaccessible; pressing "Esc" doesn't dismiss the new black screen, cannot "Alt + Tab" to running process in the background and no shortcuts work anymore (force logout doesn't work, menu launch shortcut doesn't work); only thing that works is hard shutdown by holding the power button down for five+ seconds.  This glitch has occurred quite a few time and is not a one-off error.

Majority of my time on the computer is online surfing and watching videos so this is a big problem, especially the last one where any unsaved data is lost when I have to do a hard shutdown.

If anyone knows how to fix any of these problems, I would very much appreciate your help.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1770897

- I asked the same question on ubuntuforums.org and was able to get help from many people that seems to have solved the issues I was having with fullscreen flash apps.  Here is a summary for anyone who's interested:

1) Flash-Aid extension for firefox: I'm using x64 version of firefox, java and flash; I removed my previous installation of flash64 and used this extension to install it directly from adobe labs (by lovinglinux)

2) Disable suspension of desktop effects when fullscreen apps are enabled: uncheck "suspend desktop effects for fullscreen windows" in SystemSettings -> Desktop effects -> Advanced tab (by schnelle)

The above two solved my problems but you can also try this if it persists for you:

3) [The first post on this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1770897&page=2) gives a good guide on how to configure window and application specific behavior to disable focus stealing prevention built into KWin: System Settings -> Window Behavior -> Window Rules tab (by Zorael)